# Как обрабатывать два одновременных нажатия на экран в LibGdx?

Tags: android, разработка-игр, libgdx

Я делаю игру на `LibGdx`, тапая по экрану срабатывает следующий метод для выстрела

```
public void aim() { 
    float x = Gdx.input.getX();
    float y = Gdx.input.getY();
    // получаю две переменный и дальше их уже использую.
}
```

Суть вопроса, когда я тапаю одним пальцем на экран происходит выстрел в эту точку (палец остается на экране), затем тапаю другим пальцем в другую точку, то выстрел происходит в первую точку.

Может кто-то знает как в `LibGDX` можно обрабатывать одновременные нажатия на экран?

Пытался сделать с помощью `Stage` и поделить экран на две равные части в виде `Actor`, тоже ничего хорошего не получилось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По умолчанию `getX` вам вернет первый указатель, чтобы считать следующие тапы вам надо использовать [`Gdx.input.getX(int index)`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Input.html#getX%28int%29) метод, т.е. например для второго:

```
    float x = Gdx.input.getX(1);
    float y = Gdx.input.getY(1);
```

Можно проверить нажат ли текущий указатель через `Gdx.input.isTouched`, и делать опрос в цикле, впрочем это уже детали.

Comment: Да, так все работает, спасибо!